# Ensuring propagation is complete in VHDL without an explicit click

Tags: vhdl, timing

I am looking to build a VHDL circuit which responds to an input as fast as possible, meaning I don't have an explicit clock to clock signals in and out if I don't absolutely need one.  However, I am also looking to avoid "bouncing" where one leg of a combinatorial block of logic finishes before another.

As an example, the expression `B <= A xor not not A` should clearly never assign true to B.  However, in a real implementation, the two not gates introduce delays which permit the output of that expression to flicker after A changes but the not gates have not propagated that change.  I'd like to "debounce" that circuit.

The usual, and obvious, solution is to clock the circuit, so that one never observes a transient value.  However, for this circuit, I am looking to avoid a dependence on a clock signal, and only have a network of gates.

I'd like to have something like:

```
x <= not A   -- line 1
y <= not x   -- line 2
z <= A xor y -- line 3
B <= z       -- line 4
```

such that I guarantee that line 4 occurs after line 3.

The tricky part is that I am not doing this in one block, as the exposition above might suggest.  The true behavior of the circuit is defined by two or more separate components which are using signals to communicate.  Thus once the signal chain propagates into my sub-circuit, I see nothing until the output changes, or doesn't change!

In effect, the final product I'm looking for is a procedure which can be "armed" by the inputs changing, and "triggered" by the sub-circuit announcing its outputs are fully changed.  I'd like the result to be snynthesizable so that it responds to the implementation technology.  If it's on a FPGA, it always has access to a clock, so it can use that to manage the debouncing logic.  If it's being implemented as an ASIC, the signals would have to be delayed such that any procedure which sees the "triggered" signal is 100% confident that it is seeing updated ouputs from that circuit.

I see very few synthesizable approaches to such a procedural "A happens-before B" behavior.  `wait` seems to be the "right" tool for the job, but is typically only synthesizable for use with explicit clock signals.

Comment: Ignoring the obvious detail problems with the VHDL snippets presented. conceptually you are going down the fairly well trodden path of asynchronous logic. You might want to read up on Reed-Muller cells (aka "C cells if memory serves) as a starting point, and papers from about 30 years ago by Teresa Meng. I don't know that the field has advanced much since then.

Comment: I would be curious to hear what your application is, though. Unless this is an academic exercise you would typically be better off using a clock. In particular, commercial EDA tools such as Vivado and Quartus do not support self-timed circuits.

Comment: @pc3e The particular use is trying to adapt a pre-exisiting speed independent modeling language to handle cases where some bare-minimum amount of synchronization (A happens-before B type of stuff) is required without egregious overhead.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide an interrogatory with a question mark somewhere to indicate your actual question?